# CSS background image on DIV's vertical center

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I need to get a small background image into the vertical center of that DIV using CSS.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Judging from your past questions, you seem to know about `background-image`. What is your question? Are you looking for `background-position`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To vertically center:

```
#con {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat left center;
}
```

To horizontally center:

```
#con {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: Remove the spaces after URL.

Answer (score 11):

```
#somediv {
background: url (image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

the 50% centers it horizontally and vertically.. alternatively you can use `center center`

Comment: Remove the spaces after URL