# How to center a user's view using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, resize, positioning

I have a webpage with a background image that extends (in some resolutions) beyond the width of the browser's window.

The contents of the webpage in question are centered, relative to the background image, and so I would like that the visitors to the webpage would have their **view horizontally centered** aswell.

Is that possible? If not, how would I go with **dynamically cropping** the background image, to fit the window size of the viewer?

Comment: check my answer may be that's helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676197/css-background-image-on-divs-vertical-center/5676333#5676333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the css:

Goto the `body{}` class and modify it as:

```
body
{
background: url('path-to-ur-image/image.jpg') top no-repeat;
}
```