# ol bg image should be over li bg image

Tags: css

I have to achive something like this:

[image]

I have decided to use ol with background images.

Here is my html and css:

//html

```
<ol>
    <li class="step1">
        <p>Text Text TextTextTextTextText   TextTextTextTextTextText            
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText  TextTextTextTextTextTextText </p>
    </li>
    <li class="step2">
        <p>Text Text TextTextTextTextText   TextTextTextTextTextText            
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText  TextTextTextTextTextTextText </p>
    </li>
    <li class="step3">
        <p>Text Text TextTextTextTextText   TextTextTextTextTextText            
            TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText  TextTextTextTextTextTextText </p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

//CSS

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;    
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

ol li {
    background-image: url(../images/poga_zala_fons.png), url(../images/Nr1.png);    
    background-position: -5px 0, -5px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 7px;    
}

ol li.step1 p {
    background-color: #99cc33;        
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}

ol li.step2 p {
    background-color: #ffff99;    
}

ol li.step3 p {
    background-color: #ffcc00;    
}

ol li p {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

[Here is link to webste](http://tax.allfaces.lv/manual-for-travelers/how-to-shop-tax-free)

1) There are many problems, but the first one is that I cannot get background image of ol to be over background image of paragraph background.

2) Second, I am not sure that the idea to use ol/li was the best, Maybe there are some other nice suggestions how to achive the think in image better? Please, give me some clues, I am not asking the exact sollution.

I am php programmer, but new to creating design to CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions... if you want to keep list (because of 'semantic'), here is one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfhEN/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
<li class="step1">
<div class='bgr'>
<p class='txt'>
Look for the CITYrefund.eu logo when doing your shopping- this is the sign that particular shop participate in CITYrefund Tax Free service system*. Tell the shop assistant that you want to use CITYrefund Tax Free system and show your passport or national ID card. The shop assistant will give you the SPECIAL TYPE OF FORM. Fill in and sign the customer sections of the form in the presence of the shop assistant. *If the shop isn't yet registered in CITYrefund Tax Free service system, you can always use our SPECIAL TYPE OF FORM "B" in almost any shop in Riga.
</p>
</div>
</li>
<li class="step2">
<p>You must export the goods (that is, take them out of the EU with you) by the last day of the third month after the one in which you buy them. Show your goods, till receipts and SPECIAL TYPE OF FORMS to a Latvian customs officer or to customs in the last EU country you visit. You must get your SPECIAL TYPE OF FORM checked and stamped by a customs officer.</p>
</li>
<li class="step3">
<p>Get your VAT refund by CITYrefund.eu according to your choosed options. Register your SPECIAL TYPE OF FORMS and till receipts online and then mail the original copies to our office address: CITYrefund Latvia SIA, Pakalninu iela 4, Tīraine, Latvia.</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#list {
        list-style-type:none;
        width:680px;
    }
    .step1 {

        background-image:url(number.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:319px;
        /*width:?  */
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        z-index:99;
        position:relative;


}
.step1 .bgr {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    left:166px;

    background-color:#99cc33;
    height:100%;
    /*width:?*/
}
.step1 .txt {
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:30px;


}
```

of course, you will have to tweak sizes, margins, paddings, but i hope that you get idea...

Comment: btw, what if the height of .step1 reduces? what if it is not as big as the image for ul?

Comment: @renathy, images and 'text holders' heights should be same... inside that holders -> try to set text position to fit your needs.

Comment: it doesn't fit my needs, cause client would like to change text later

Comment: @renathy, then just image numbers (circles) should be used, and must be placed in vertical center: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676197/css-background-image-on-divs-vertical-center... so little modification is needed, if you could provide background image, i could try something...

Comment: http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/poga_zala_fons.png here is bg image (it is without number, but I will add number if necessary)

Comment: huh, don't have idea... variable heights are problem, i am thinking about jquery solutions, but... someone will probably know...